# Checking periodic table words

Tags: code-golf

Given a sequence of letters, write a program to construct it using symbols on the periodic table. For example, given the input `bacon`, the program should output:

```
BaCoN
BAcON
BaCON
```

Note that capitalization is important. Standard loopholes apply. If a word can't be formed, any error message may be printed.

*Edit*: All possible ways to make the sequence must be output.

Comment: I like the question, but I'd suggest expanding it a bit more to avoid cheap tactics.

Comment: I read that challenge before posting mine; I believe that they use different algorithms. This one talks about permutations of symbols and the other can be solved with a pretty unsophisticated algorithm. In general, I think they have different intents.

Comment: @ɐɔıʇǝɥʇuʎs How would you suggest expanding the challenge?

Comment: I've edited the question to hopefully further distinguish it from the earlier one.