# Play scrabble with the periodic table

Tags: code-golf

You've got a set of tiles with the symbols from the periodic table. Each symbol appears once. You're thinking up words to make but you want to know if it's possible or not.

### The Challenge

Write a program in your favourite language that will take in a string as an input parameter. You may assume that input is not null, has no spaces and consists of ASCII characters.

Your program should take that string and output a truthy value if that word can made up of symbols from the periodic table of elements, and a falsey value if the word cannot.

To make this challenge more difficult, you may not use a symbol twice. So if you use Nitrogen `N` you may not use `N` again in the same word.

### Rules

Standard loopholes are not allowed. You may use symbols from elements 1-118 (Hydrogen to Unun­octium). You can find a list of all the elements [here](http://pastebin.com/DNZMWmuf). You may read the list of symbols in from a file or input arguments if you wish.

### Test Cases:

```
Laos - true (LaOs)
Amputation - true (AmPuTaTiON)
Heinous - true (HeINoUS)
Hypothalamus - true (HYPoThAlAmUS)
Singapore - true (SiNGaPoRe)
Brainfuck - true (BRaInFUCK)
Candycane - false
```

This is a code golf challenge, shortest code wins.

**BEFORE YOU CLOSE AS DUPLICATE:** While this may seem similar to [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/6284/16043), I feel it is different because it is not 'Generate a list of all words that are possible from the periodic table', it is 'Take in arbitrary input and determine if it can be made from the periodic table'

Comment: I like this one, I look at it later

Comment: There's [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/34641/8478) which is more closely related but was itself closed as a duplicate of the challenge you linked. I think the fact you can only use a symbol once is the greatest differentiation between the challenges though. In terms of golfing I doubt there's a better way than brute forcing all possible words and checking if the input is among them.

Comment: A question though, what elements should we use? Do Uus, Uuo, etc. count?

Comment: @Bálint The challenge says 1-118.

Comment: _"You may read the list of symbols in from a file if you wish."_ - how do we count it? Is size of the file added to the code length? Or we can use it for free?

Comment: Can we take the list of elements as an argument to the program?

Comment: @Qwertiy, the size of the file is free, but the bytes to read it in are not.

Comment: Boron, Radium, Iodine, Nitrogen, Fluorine, Uranium, Carbon, Potassium.

Comment: @Neil gets votes just by saying a few elements.

Comment: What about the case of the word/symbols?

Comment: @Neil Swap the Iodine and Nitrogen for Indium.

Comment: @SuperJedi224 I should have made my answer output all the solutions instead of working out manually why it returned `true`.

Comment: Why did you allow to read in the element's names as a file? I find it much more challenging (and therefore interesting) to encode them in the source code itself.

Comment: I'll just leave [this](http://elemensus.com) here in case anyone else thought this would be a fun board game XD

Answer (score 3):

### 05AB1E, 16 bytes

```
œvyŒ€J})˜Ùvy²Q}O
```

**Explained**

```
œv                # for each permutation of the list of elements
  yŒ              # get all sublist of elements
    €J            # join as strings to form the words possible to spell
      })˜Ù        # convert to list of unique spellable strings
          vy²Q}   # compare each word with input word
               O  # sum giving 1 if the word is found, else 0
```

**Warning:** Extremely slow. I recommend testing on a much smaller subset of elements in the online interpreter.

Takes list of elements as first argument.
Takes word to test as second argument.
Returns 1 for true and 0 for false.

[Try it online on a small subset of elements](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=xZN2ecWS4oKsSn0py5zDmXZ5wrJRfU8&input=WydoJywgJ2hlJywgJ2xpJywgJ2JlJywgJ2InLCAnYyddCmJlY2xp)

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 7 bytes

```
spc~@l.
```

Call with the list of symbols (all lowercase) as Input, and the word as Output, e.g. `run_from_atom('spc~@l.', ["he":"n":"o":"li"], "Nohe").` .

**Warning:** this is extremely inefficent when all symbols are in the list.

#### Explanation

```
spc        Create a string from a permutation of a subset of the Input
   ~@l.    This string can unify with the lowercase version of the Output
```

Comment: @Downvoter care to explain?

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (Firefox 48 or earlier), 103 bytes

```
f=(w,e=`
H
He
... (list of elements not included in the byte count) ...
Uus
Uuo
`)=>!w||e.match(/\w+/g).some(s=>!w.search(s,`i`)&&f(w.slice(s.length),e.replace(`
${s}
`,`
`)))
```

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth - 13 bytes

Just checks if any partition of lowercased input has all parts in the periodic table.

```
sm.A}RQd./rzZ
```

On mobile, so couldn't set up an actual test suite, but try [this](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=sm.A%7DRQd.%2FrzZ&input=%22la%22%2C%22c%22%2C%22os%22%0Alaos&debug=0).

Comment: You wrote this on a phone!?

Comment: This doesn't ensure an element is not used multiple times. [Example.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=sm.A%7DRQd.%2FrzZ&input=%22ca%22%2C%22n%22%2C%22dy%22%2C%22ne%22%0Acandycane&debug=0)

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 11 bytes

```
s}RySQSM./z
```

[Try it online.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=s%7DRySQSM.%2Fz&input=%22ca%22%2C%22n%22%2C%22dy%22%2C%22ne%22%0Acandycane&debug=0) [Test suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=s%7DRySQSM.%2Fz&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22al%22%2C%22am%22%2C%22h%22%2C%22po%22%2C%22s%22%2C%22th%22%2C%22u%22%2C%22y%22%0Ahypothalamus%0A%22ca%22%2C%22n%22%2C%22dy%22%2C%22ne%22%0Acandycane&debug=0&input_size=2)

Written on my phone, but should work. **Very slow for a large number of elements or a long string.**

#### Explanation

- Take all partitions (`./`) of the input (`z`).
- Sort (`S`) each partition (`M`).
- For each partition (`R`), see if it is in (`}`) the list of all subsets (`y`) of the sorted (`S`) periodic table given as input (`Q`).
- Sum (`s`) the resulting list of booleans.